# Extending BasicTabbedPaneUI for multiple rows of tabs

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I'm attempting to extend BasicTabbedPaneUI (Java/Swing), and I have hit a wall.
It almost works, except when there are too many tabs to fit into a single row. Automatically, the new tabs are put onto new rows.
However, my painting routines seem to only cater for a single row, and so it looks completely messed up in that situation. After quite a bit of googling, I understand that the `BasicTabbedPaneUI` is using the `WRAP_TAB_LAYOUT`, but I have no idea how to modify my code to cater for it (and for that matter, what about the scrolling layout)!

My example is based on the AquaBarTabbedPaneUI from http://www.jroller.com/DhilshukReddy/entry/custom_jtabbedpane (note that this suffers from the same multiple-row problem as my version). I'm getting quite frustrated as there seems to be very little out there about extending `BasicTabbedPaneUI` except for very simple examples.

I would be very grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: why ...............................

Comment: Mostly because the standard LaFs don't look that good.

Comment: I thought JTabbedPane could thus by default?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yeah, JTabbedPane does have the WRAP_TAB_LAYOUT yes, but the _painting_ performed by some custom BasicTabbedPaneUI doesn't necessarily do it, at least not properly.

Comment: read the source code of ui's that support it (like metal, afair) and do the same ... nothing we can do for you

Comment: I was fearing someone might say that... :( Thanks for the help!